# Python: TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation?

Tags: python

can't run python script. 
error msg: TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation
already used 10 times autopep8 -i file.py

code:

```
def main():
    # read_pdf( "docs/3.pdf" )

    extanstions = {}

    for root, dirs, files in os.walk('X:\backup'):
        for _file in files:
            extension = os.path.splitext(_file)[1]
            extension = extension[1:]

            try:
                extanstions[extension] += 1
            except:
                extanstions[extension] = 1

            print(os.path.join(root, _file) + " >> " + extension)

        print(extanstions.keys())
    return 0


main()
```

Comment: Seems like a really clear error message, right?

Comment: The error already says the problem. Try to press `SHIFT + ALT + F` if in VSCode to see if it fixes it. That trys to format your script.

Comment: Always read and try to understand the error you get. Python has very friendly error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use tabs and spaces crossed over in your code this error comes up. Just replace all spaces by a tab or all tabs by spaces. Then the error wont come up anymore.

I mean for the indents, not in generell xD

This error often comes up after copy pasting code from a website in combination with your code because the indents on the website might be spaces and in your code the indents are tabs.

Comment: I used autopep8